# Getting labels from StringIndexer stages within pipeline in Spark (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `Spark` and `pyspark` and I have a `pipeline` set up with a bunch of `StringIndexer` objects, that I use to encode the string columns to columns of indices:

```
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column + '_index').setHandleInvalid('skip')
            for column in list(set(data_frame.columns) - ignore_columns)]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
new_data_frame = pipeline.fit(data_frame).transform(data_frame)
```

The problem is, that I need to get the list of labels for each `StringIndexer` object after it gets fitted. For a single column and a single `StringIndexer` without a pipeline, it's an easy task. I can just access the `labels` attribute after fitting the indexer on the `DataFrame`:

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="name", outputCol="name_index")
indexer_fitted = indexer.fit(data_frame)
labels = indexer_fitted.labels
new_data_frame = indexer_fitted.transform(data_frame)
```

However when I use the pipeline, this doesn't seem possible, or at least I don't know how to do this.

So I guess my question comes down to:
Is there a way to access the labels that were used during the indexing process for each individual column?

Or will I have to ditch the pipeline in this use-case, and for example loop through the list of `StringIndexer` objects and do it manually? (I'm sure that would possible. However using the pipeline would just be a lot nicer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example data and `Pipeline`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, StringIndexerModel

df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", "foo"), ("b", "bar")], ("x1", "x2"))

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[
    StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol='{}_index'.format(c))
    for c in df.columns
])

model = pipeline.fit(df)
```

Extract from `stages`:

```
# Accessing _java_obj shouldn't be necessary in Spark 2.3+
{x._java_obj.getOutputCol(): x.labels 
for x in model.stages if isinstance(x, StringIndexerModel)}
```

```
{'x1_index': ['a', 'b'], 'x2_index': ['foo', 'bar']}
```

From metadata of the transformed `DataFrame`:

```
indexed = model.transform(df)

{c.name: c.metadata["ml_attr"]["vals"]
for c in indexed.schema.fields if c.name.endswith("_index")}
```

```
{'x1_index': ['a', 'b'], 'x2_index': ['foo', 'bar']}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if we can modify indexer_fitted.labels when performing transform?