# StringIndexerModel inputCol

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a cluster with spark 2.1 and a process that at the end writes on file a `PipelineModel`, which contains a `StringIndexerModel`. I can locally (with spark 2.3) load the pipeline and inspect the `StringIndexerModel`. What it appears very strange is that the method and fields differ between the two versions, even if they read the same files. In particular, with spark 2.1 the field `inputCol` appears to not be there even if it's obviously needed to make the StringIndexer work.

This is what I get.

Spark 2.1:

```
pip1 = PipelineModel.load("somepath")
si = pip1.stages[0]
si
#StringIndexer_494eb1f86ababc8540e2
si.inputCol
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#AttributeError: 'StringIndexerModel' object has no attribute 'inputCol'
```

Spark 2.3

```
pip1 = PipelineModel.load("somepath")
si = pip1.stages[0]
si
#StringIndexer_494eb1f86ababc8540e2
si.inputCol
#Param(parent='StringIndexer_494eb1f86ababc8540e2', name='inputCol', doc='input column name')
```

I understand that methods and fields might change from one version to another, but the `inputCol` must be somewhere in the object, since it is essential to make `fit` or `transform` work. Is there a way to extract the `inputCol` in spark 2.1 with PySpark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heavy lifting in Spark ML is done by the internal Java objects (`_java_obj`), that's why objects can work, even if internal are never fully exposed in Python API. This of course limits what can be done without drilling into Java API, and since Spark 2.3 `Params` are exposed in PySpark models ([SPARK-10931](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10931)).

In previous versions you can access internal model, and fetch data from there. However if you want to get a value of the `Param` you should use `get*` method, not the `Param` as such.

```
si._java_obj.getInputCol()
```

Related:

- [pyspark: getting the best model's parameters after a gridsearch is blank {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46110563/6910411)
- [How to get best params after tuning by pyspark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41908418/6910411)
- [Getting labels from StringIndexer stages within pipeline in Spark (pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45885044/6910411)

Comment: Great, thanks! I was getting crazy in digging all the java methods and didn't find the solution you mentioned!